# Wrong width/height inflating AlertDialog from XML

Tags: android, layout, android-alertdialog

I'm having problems inflating an AlertDialog with a custom XML. The problem is that it doesn't respect the width/height I've specified.

**volume.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp" android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="250dip"
    android:id="@+id/layoutRoot">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Volume:"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"></TextView>
    <SeekBar android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/volumeBar"
        android:minHeight="10dp" android:maxHeight="15dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"></SeekBar>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:textSize="22dp"
        android:text="20%" android:id="@+id/volumeText"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Code:**

```
    Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) this
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View VolumeView = mInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.volume, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layoutRoot));
    alertbox.setView(VolumeView);
    alertDialog = alertbox.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: can I ask you to be a little more specific. I mean what did u expect and what are u seeing ??

Comment: Sorry, I expected 250dip of width and I get wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be the `layoutRoot` you are providing as the second parameter of your call to `mInflater.inflate()`.  This will affect the layout of the XML file being inflated.

Your question needs more information for anyone to give a better answer than this.